# Same domain - 2 separate servers

Tags: apache, seo, load-balancing

I have a website that runs on a framework on a LAMP stack.

Now I want to extend this website by adding a bunch of new pages, but served from a different framework on a separate LAMP stack on another server that is prepared to handle more traffic.

I don't want this traffic to pass by the original website as it will be a burden to be processed by the framework. However, I can afford to have apache forwarding the traffic request to a specific folder forwarded to a separate server with a different IP address.

For example:

mydomain.com/ -> goes to server A,

mydomain.com/folder1/ -> goes to server B

How can I accomplish this with apache?

I can even afford setup a separated server to handle the separation of these request, so each server will only receive the requests it is intended to process.

Another option could be to set a subdomain like ww2.mydomain.com pointed to the IP of a separated server but will this affect my SEO ranking?

What are other options and what would be the best option for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive.
Example location for mydomain.com virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ...
    <Location /folder1/>
        ProxyPass http://serverb/
        SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
        SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
    </Location>
</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: If the main website is: http: //www.domain and I use ProxyPass http: //serverB.domain, will the end user continue browsing the pages on serverB as they are in serverA http: //www.domain ?

Comment: If there are no absolute URLs or direct links from `serverB.domain` to itself or another domain, this should looks like all content is loaded from `www.domain/folder1/`.